# Is DAO a good practice in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring from a tutorial in Udemy, but the author uses Spring Boot 1.5.6 and I'm a little unsure about what he's doing. In a JPA example, he created a `Client` entity (`Serializable`) and then a `ClientDAO` interface plus its implementation. The implementation looks like this:

```
@Repository
public class ClientDaoImpl implements IClientDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public List<Client> findAll() {
        return em.createQuery("from Client").getResultList();
    }
}
```

Is it a good practice to do that? I've watched a video before where the author used `CrudRepository` and made a service without implementing anything, let alone using this sort of SQL. Is this because it's an outdated version of Spring Boot or is this a good approach? This looks a lot like old JavaEE instead of Spring 5. Should I ignore that and do it with a CrudRepository and services?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly fine. The example that you showed simply doesn't use Spring Data - it uses Spring DAO + JPA integration. Which is fine. Spring Data is yet another abstraction over this. With ORMs the typical possibilities that you have are:

- Pure Hibernate + Spring DAO
- JPA + Spring DAO
- JPA + Spring Data

Which one to use is often dictated by personal preferences and experience. E.g. I'm okay with using Spring Data but my personal choice is always Hibernate + Spring Dao. So it's not a question of good or bad practices.

Your project needs also influence the choice - e.g. performance requirements may lead you to abandoning ORMs in favour of Spring JDBC and native SQL queries.

One important thing to note - you don't lose time by learning low-level approaches. So if you don't know whether learning JDBC or pure JPA is a waste of time - that's never the case. High-level API is always based on low-level API and you can't become expert in the former without learning the latter.

Answer (score 4):

It's always a good practice if you can implement the service with as little code as possible. So if we can create a DAO service by declaring only the interface, it's better and is recommended by the official documentation for [spring DATA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).

```
interface ClientDao extends CrudRepository<Cliente, Long> {
}
```

However, for the purpose of learning, it's better to practice with the old way to understand how it works.

Comment: Ah I see, good point. In the case of using the CrudRepository, what if I wanted to do a complex query that's not supported by default? Would I have to make the DAO and use that `em.createQuery("from Client").getResultList()` syntax?

Comment: If you want to implement a complex query with Spring data, the efficient way is to use specifications as describe in the official documentation by implementing the interface JpaSpecificationExecutor.

Comment: Also please upvote or mark as response if it was helpfull. Thanks.